# Whats difference in below three snippets

Tags: php, function

I found below snippets very confusing. The Snippet 1 is staightforward and everybody knows about it. What does the other two snippets do? What are their significances and which to use for what reasons?

```
# Snippet 1
public function __construct (array $items) {
    $this->items = $items;
}

# Snippet 2
public function __construct (array $items) {
    $this->items = function () use ($items) {
        return $items;
    };
}

# Snippet 3
public function __construct (array $items) {
    $this->items = (function (...$items) {
        return $items;
    })(...$items);
}
```

The third snippet is from [SOLIDay 2015 - Marco Pivetta - Extremely defensive PHP #7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS0Nn_ncH-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippets 1 and 3 will provide you with similar result, except the `$this->items` array in the third snippet won't contain any of the original keys.

Snippet 2 is the more interesting one, because it will contain an anonymous function instead of a value. You can use this, if you want to postpone some expensive manipulation of the input, that is not used for all execution paths. You also retain the original input for each of those calls, which would be useful, if you need to perform various transformations on the input, but each of transforms required access to 'pristine' input.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet 2 have used PHP Anonymous functions. Read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php Example #3 contains your answer.

Your code snipet 3 have used PHP Anonymous function with PHP Variable-length argument lists. Read this page: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new